# Missing HTTP flag and Secure flag on form_key and mage-messages

Tags: cookie

As per my security checking and testing in Magento 2.1, I see that secure cookie or HTTP only flag not set on form_key and mage-messages.For the security reason, we need the cookie to be secure. Can someone please help me on this.

[image]

Comment: Any solution to this?